# Merge data from two cells from the same column in different rows in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am having trouble searching for an answer to this question, because of my lack of knowledge about the terminology and SQL, even though I know it probably exists.

I have a database with the following tables:
desc pkm;

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pkm_code        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pkm_name        | varchar(32)   | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| pkm_category    | varchar(32)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pkm_description | varchar(1280) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| pkm_weight      | float         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| evolution_code  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

desc poketype;

```
+---------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pkm_code            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type_code           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| poketype_is_primary | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

desc type;

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| type_code | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type_name | varchar(32) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And so far I have the following SQL command:

```
SELECT pkm.pkm_code, pkm.pkm_name,type.type_name FROM poketype
    JOIN pkm ON pkm.pkm_code=poketype.pkm_code
    JOIN type ON poketype.type_code=type.type_code
    WHERE pkm.pkm_code<=151
    ORDER BY pkm_code;
```

Which displays the primary and secondary types on separate lines.
How would I get both types to display on the same row for dual-type pokemon?

My current results:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| pkm_code  | pkm_name    | type_name |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1         | Bulbasaur   | grass     |
| 1         | Bulbasaur   | poison    |
```

Desired results:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| pkm_code  | pkm_name    | type_name   |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1         | Bulbasaur   | grass,poison|
```

(Yes, bulbasaur is a dual type. I was surprised too!)

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql's [group_concat() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to combine values from different records in a single value:

```
SELECT pkm.pkm_code, pkm.pkm_name, group_concat(type.type_name) as typename FROM poketype
    JOIN pkm ON pkm.pkm_code=poketype.pkm_code
    JOIN type ON poketype.type_code=type.type_code
    WHERE pkm.pkm_code<=151
    GROUP BY pkm.pkm_code, pkm.pkm_name;
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really work. It concats *everything* in the column, I just the cells in `poketype` where `pkm_code` is the same to be concated

Comment: I think you missed the group by clause. It is in the last row of the query in my answer.